# How do I copy and paste seperately?

Tags: terminal, cp, copy-paste

I know for the `cp` command you have to specify the source(s) and destination. But what if I have to copy say all folders under `src` folder, **do some other operations**, and then `paste` later on?

In short, can I separately copy and paste in a bash shell or a terminal?

Comment: Are you doing this in a terminal? Do you mean simply to copy the src paths via copy and then paste them as text in the terminal? It's unclear exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you need to perform other operations in between?

Comment: @slm no.. not the paths, the content to be copied.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams just wanted to know if this is possible. Haven't come across this situation yet but was curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question right, you are thinking of the copy/paste functionality found in graphical file managers, where you "mark" the files you want to copy, navigate to their destination and paste them there.

To answer your question, in short: No. What you want is not possible on in a normal bash shell. To delay such an operation is certainly possible via scripting, but I am not sure that it is worth the effort in this case.

Comment: yes.. you got the question right.. sorry if its misleading.. I'm accepting this answer that it cannot be done.. (maybe because it's not desirable at all)